# Is there a standard for storing and parsing strings for calendar date recurrence?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, recurrence, rfc5545

I am trying to store recurrence event information into a database.  I want to store recorder into a a Database table with the following fields.

- Start Date  - Datetime
- End Date - DateTime
- RecurrencePattern - string

I wanted to see if there was already some standard format to store the RecurrencePattern in and an associated library to parse out this string recurrenPattern and a start / end date and convert into a set of dates.  I see [this exists](https://github.com/skyporter/rrule_parser/blob/master/rrecur-parser-tests.js) for javascript so maybe a port to C# or something similar ?

To serialize the event to the db, do i really have to create a new iCalendar and serialize a calendar for each event ?  Would there be a way to simply serialize the event by itself to the db using this library?

### Updated question regarding DDay.iCal per Jon Skeet's answer:

As per jon skeet's suggestion, i started looking at DDay.iCal and it looks very good.  My one follow up question is that it seems to only read a full ical (ics) at a time from disk in the example.  In my case i am just storing events independently in a database table.  What would be the best way:

1. To read in these events from the DB
2. To save independent events to the DB (each event is a row in a db table)

using this library?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but a good model to represent recurrence in calendars can be found [here (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf)

Comment: You could store a cron string as well. that would represent the recurrence of an event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) library. Can't say I've used it, but that's the one that a quick search for iCalendar and C# found... (iCalendar or [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) is where that Javascript format comes from.)

In my experience with these things on other platforms, recurrences get complicated *really* quickly. If you can limit your scope from the start, you'll have a much better change of success IMO.

Comment: thanks Jon, this library seems very useful. I added a followup question around thoughts on the best way to persist given that i am persisting each event to a row in a DB table.

Comment: @leora: I suspect you could just persist the RRULE, but it's been a little while since I've done any iCal work.